# Группировка строк используя PHPExcell

Tags: php, phpexcel

Надо создать экселевский файл из данных массива.
Есть массив со следующей структурой

Регион / ТП / Филиал / Город

Группировка строк должна быть по городам в филиале (т.е. нажимаем на филиал и показываются все города в этом филиале) и по региону.

```
    Санкт-Петербург
    Санкт-Петербург, г. Красное Село
    Санкт-Петербург, г. Кронштадт
    Санкт-Петербург, г. Павловск
  + Санкт-Петербургский ф-л
+ Северо-Западный
```

Группировку по городам сделал. Нажимаешь на + строки ф-л и открывают/закрываются города.

```
$i = 2;
foreach ($structure as $region_key => $region_val) {
    foreach ($region_val as $tp_key => $tp_val) {
        foreach ($tp_val as $filial_key => $filial_val) {
            foreach ($filial_val as $city_key => $city_val) {
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setOutlineLevel(2);
                $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setVisible(true);
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Не пойму как сделать группировку по региону. Для филиалов указываю уровень 2, для региона 1, но не получается, т.к. группировать уровни надо по порядку, т.е. сначала уровень 1 потом уровень 2. Но дело в том, что я не знаю сколько будет строк в регионе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setShowSummaryBelow(false);
```

чтобы при группировке список раскрывался вниз, + будет сверху

Перед

```
foreach ($filial_val as $city_key => $city_val) {
```

добавил

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setOutlineLevel(1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($i)->setVisible(true);
```

теперь все хорошо с группировкой.